# what C++ style syntax does this belong to

Tags: c++, syntax, styles

Recently I came across a snippet similar to the following:

```
int a  <:20:>;
int b;
void foo()
<% 
 printf("Hello world"); 
 a <: ++b :> = 440;
%>
```

What C++ style/syntax does this belong to? 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: looks like the source is feed through a special purpose pre-processor.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Nope. That's legal C++ and quite entertaining during code reviews ;)

Comment: OMG: you learn something new every day.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: True that :)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: It must be. This feels like gibberish and is a nice way of confusing people :)

Comment: @jogojapan The two questions are definitely related. Thanks for the link to other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're called [digraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs):

```
Digraph Equivalent
  <:         [
  :>         ]
  <%         {
  %>         }
  %:         #
```

They're supported because in some countries few symbols might not be present on their keyboards, so they can combine keys such as `<` and `:` to form equivalent of`[`, and so on. The wikipedia entry also describes [trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs).